# Clone an initial Ubuntu 11.10 installation for different users

Tags: installation, users, clone

I have a question and hope you guys would be able to help me out.

I am going to make an fresh Ubuntu 11.10 installation. While installing, I would create the user "chris". Afterwards I would configure the desktop and install lots of stuff for the user "chris". Some of this stuff would be i.e. RVM (ruby version manager) which will create lots of files in my /home/chris folder. So at the end there would be lots of stuff in my /home/chris folder, incl. files refering to "/home/chris/some_stuff/...", etc.

When all is set and done, I would make an image of the installation using fsarchiver and restore the image to 2 other identical laptops. So far everything works perfect!

The problem is:
The 2 other laptops need to have 2 different users: "marco" and "flo". Those 2 users need exactly the installed stuff I have in /home/chris. So their home folder would be /home/marco and /home/flo.

How do I change the user name from "chris" to "marco" after restoring the image to Marco's laptop? My initial user account /home/chris won't make any sense on Marco's laptop, right?

And here comes the most important question:
How will I manage to find out all files which contain the string "/home/chris" 
 and change it to "/home/marco"?

Maybe there is a better way of making a default install on a default user, backup the installation and then redistribute it to any other user. Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: try remastersys & copy your config gile to /etc/skel

Answer (score 2):

With the Alternative disk you can do [an OEM/Prepare for End User Configuration installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview). After installation you can log in as `oem` and customise away. After running `sudo oem-config-prepare`, the `oem` user is nuked and on the next boot the user is asked to set up their user account.

Now you have two options for spreading this to more than one computer:

- You could go through the (frankly) tedious process of remastering the disk so you create a custom installation disk for the users. I'm not even sure how to remaster the Alternative disk but I'm sure it's possible...
- Or you could install in OEM mode and get to the point where you've got the system prepped and have run `oem-config-prepare`, then take an image of the disk with Clonezilla (or other) and zap that image into the rest of your machines. On boot they'll each be asked to set up a user and that's what you're after. It'll probably take up more space but if you have a fast wired network, it shouldn't take too long and it's almost zero-effort for each machine.

If you want to have specific things in the home directory of the new user, you should copy them into `/etc/skel` during the oem preparation (ie before you run `oem-config-prepare`). These files will be copied out when the first real user is generated.

This allows you to store settings, special directory setup and things like that. You don't have to copy over the entire contents of `/home/oem/` - you can pick and choose.

Comment: How do I get the OEM ISO for Ubuntu 11.10 in order to create a CD/DVD?

Comment: @Chris it's just [the alternative disk](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download). The installer is text-mode but it's mostly all there. Probably safest trying it in a VM before rinsing any real machines if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: I think this is the file I was looking for: http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso

Comment: And I am familiar both with real machines and VM. Only the task I described in the topic is new to me. :-)

Comment: I have done everything as you suggested. It does only partially. All installed apps who do not need any changes in the /home/chris folder, are also available AFTER the new user has been created. This means that i.e. apps like traceroute, openssh and some more would be available out of the box for the new user.

Comment: Other apps who write things in /home/chris would loose any settings and will have to be recreated (manually) once the new user has logged in.

Comment: I have found some new hints over here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1561714 .... I'll try again using /etc/skel.

Comment: @Chris I see what you mean! Good point. I've updated the question to include some information about `/etc/skel`

Comment: ok, well done. I will keep ya updated on my progress. ;-)